# How to generate QR Code with Colors for each Pixel?

Tags: java, android, qr-code, zxing

I am doing a project with the QR Code. I want to change the color for each pixel.I tried but it doesn't work. Help me.

I tried: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vA1tQ.jpg

```
...

private int color_1 = 0x000000, color_2 = 0xffffffff, color_3 = Color.RED;

for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                    if (bitMatrix.get(j, i)) {
                        if (j == 0) {
                            pixels[i * width + j] = color_3; // RED
                        } else {
                            pixels[i * width + j] = color_1; // BLACK
                        }
                    } else {
                        pixels[i * width + j] = color_2; // WHITE
                    }
                }
            }
...
```

I received: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHCuY.jpg

It seems that there is an existing QR code overlay.

Comment: How do you define color_1,2,3?

Comment: RGB_565 system uses 5 bits for red, 6 for green and 5 for blue

Comment: @markmark I edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting red to 0x8F00. I think you encode the color as RGB-565, but Color.RED might be 24 bit, so there is an overflow.